# What does $\bigoplus\limits_{\mathbb N} \mathbb Z$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, notation, combinatorial-group-theory

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304752/difference-between-free-and-finitely-generated-modules/304774#304774) question, $\bigoplus_{\mathbb N} \mathbb Z$ is given as an example of a group that is freely generated but not finitely generated. A similar question is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131241/what-does-bigoplus-mean-when-applied-to-two-sets) but it has been closed because it does not provide the context in which the operator is used.

Comment: [Direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum). As a set it consists of sequences $(z_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ such that $z_n\in\Bbb{Z}$ for all $n$, and only finitely many of them are non-zero. The latter condition marks the difference between a direct sum and a direct product. The group operation is that of $\Bbb{Z}$, i.e. addition, done componentwise.

Comment: Notation (perhaps confusing?):$$\bigoplus_{\mathbb N} \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\oplus\cdots$$ where there the copies of $\mathbb Z$ are indexed by $\mathbb N$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18932/why-is-cofiniteness-included-in-the-definition-of-direct-sum-of-submodules) for more details.